# Compiling code for AT91SAM3U and a basic USB stack

Tags: usb, arm, cortex-m3, development-tools

I am about to start working on some small application that has to run on an AT91SAM3U ARM [Cortex-M3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Cortex-M3) processor.

- What good tool suite / development kit should I use?
- Is it possible to find code for a basic USB stack which allows EP links for sending control and bulk transfers using a driver we develop using [libusb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libusb)?

Comment: What are "EP links"?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a small application then there's a free version of IAR's Development tools ([Embedded Workbench for ARM kickstart edition](http://supp.iar.com/Download/SW/?item=EWARM-KS32)) The significant limitation on this is that it will not link applications above 32k in size.

Atmel also produce a USB stack (in [At91lib](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card.asp?tool_id=4568&category_id=163&family_id=605&subfamily_id=2086)), which provides a reasonably simple interface for sending/receiving on endpoints.